# Remove the www from the url in wordpress?

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

Hello guys i have wordpress site When i open the site with **url(www)** .It's replace the **www** from url like example:

I have site url `httr://www.test.com` and after brows the site i see the url its look like `http://test.com` .

I have confuser it's problem of **.htaccess** file are some thing else ma .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Guys if you have solution please share with mi .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to update your site URL in your database. From httt://www.test.com to http://test.com

Take a look at this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

And this to update your DB : http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Thanks for answer superb you give mi such a great like http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL which help mi more!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the WordPress general settings? what's the URL there? I believe it's a matter of WP and not a htaccess issue.